# Replace dataframe column values based on matching id in another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to replace values in a dataframe based on values in a different dataframe. Please assume there are other columns in both dataframes. A simple example:

df1

```
id    name  ......
123   city a
456   city b
789   city c
789   city c
456   city b
123   city a
```

so on and so forth

df2

```
id    name  ......
123   City A
456   City B
789   City C
```

So the resulting df should be:

```
id    name  ......
123   City A
456   City B
789   City C
789   City C
456   City B
123   City A
```

I tried out with a few merge options in pandas with no luck. Is there an easy way to replace all the values in the first dataframe with the values from the second dataframe based on a match on `id`?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
df1['New name']=df1.id.map(df2.set_index('id').name)
```

Update

```
namediff=df1.columns.difference(df2.columns).tolist()+['id']
df3=df2.drop(df2.columns.difference(df1.columns),axis=1)
df1=df1[namediff].merge(df3,on='id')
```

Or

```
df1=df1.set_index('id')
df1.update(df2.set_index('id'))
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, there are other columns in both the dataframes, but all I'm concerned about is just matching on the id and the column names

Comment: @codingenthusiast check with merge

Comment: this will bring other columns into the dataframe as well

Comment: if df2 has other columns, wouldn't this merge into df1?

Comment: @codingenthusiast if that happen , check the update

Comment: still not working. all I need is to match on id column from both and replace names on df1 from df2, without affecting any other columns on both dataframes

Comment: this assumes that `name` column is named the same in both df, correct? and it won't add any columns from df2 to df1?

Comment: @codingenthusiast yes

Comment: Is there a way to enforce this if the `name` columns are different in the two dataframes?

Comment: @codingenthusiast I have no idea about your real environment , if you have additional follow up question , please open a new one